# Conditionally selecting values from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe in which I would like to determine how many unique bird species each person saw who participated in my "Big Year".

I've tried using a list comprehension and for loops to iterate over each row and determine if it's unique using .is_unique(), but that seems to be the source of much of my distress. I can get a list of all the unique species with .unique(), quite nicely, but I would like to somehow get the people associated with those birds.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Species':['woodpecker', 'woodpecker', 'dove', 'mockingbird'], 'Birder':['Steve', 'Ben','Ben','Greg']})

ben_unique_bird = [x for x in range(len(df['Species'])) if df['Birder'][x]=='Ben' and df['Species'][x].is_unique()]
```

Edit: I think I'm unclear in this- I want to get a list of birds that each person saw that no one else did. So the output would be something like (Steve, 0), (Ben, 1), (Greg, 1), in whatever format.

Thanks!

Comment: To illustrate your code to make things much better.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and welcome. I've updated the code and tried to clarify what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a helper series via [`pd.DataFrame.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and then use `GroupBy` + `sum`:

```
counts = data.assign(dup_flag=df['Species'].duplicated(keep=False))\
             .groupby('Birder')['dup_flag'].sum().astype(int)

for name, count in counts.items():
    print(f'{name} saw {count} bird(s) that no one else saw')
```

Result:

```
Ben saw 1 bird(s) that no one else saw
Greg saw 0 bird(s) that no one else saw
Steve saw 1 bird(s) that no one else saw
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with list comprehension quite easily.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Species':['woodpecker', 'woodpecker', 'dove', 'mockingbird'], 'Birder':['Steve', 'Ben','Ben','Greg']})

matches = [(row[1], row[2]) for row in df.itertuples() if (row[1],row[2]) not in matches]
```

This gives a list of tuples as output:

```
[('Steve', 'woodpecker'), ('Ben', 'woodpecker'), ('Ben', 'dove'), ('Greg', 'mockingbird')]
```

Answer (score 1):

name of unique birds they saw

```
 ben_unique_bird = df[df['Birder'] == 'Ben']['Species'].unique()
```

number of unique birds they saw

```
len(df[df['Birder'] == 'Ben']['Species'].unique())
```

Recommended method 1 to get a table

```
df.groupby(['Birder']).agg({"Species": lambda x: x.nunique()})
```

same method broken down

```
for i in df['Birder'].unique():
    print (" Name ",i," Distinct count ",len(df[df['Birder'] == i]['Species'].unique())," distinct bird names ",df[df['Birder'] == i]['Species'].unique())
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a terrible way of doing what I want, but it works. Please let me know if you have a more efficient way of doing this, because I know there has to be one.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Species':['woodpecker', 'woodpecker', 'dove', 'mockingbird'], 'Birder':['Steve', 'Ben','Ben','Greg']})

ben_birds = []
steve_birds = []
greg_birds = []

#get all the names of the birds that people saw and put them in a list
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    if row['Birder'] == 'Bright':
        ben_birds.append(row['Species'])
    elif row['Birder'] == 'Filios':
        steve_birds.append(row['Species'])
    else:
        greg_birds.append(row['Species'])

duplicates=[]
#compare each of the lists to look for duplicates, and make a new list with those
for bird in ben_birds:
    if (bird in steve_birds) or (bird in greg_birds):
        duplicates.append(bird)

for bird in steve_birds:
    if (bird in greg_birds):
        duplicates.append(bird)

#if any of the duplicates are in a list, remove those birds
for bird in ben_birds:
    if bird in duplicates:
        ben_birds.remove(bird)

for bird in steve_birds:
    if bird in duplicates:
        steve_birds.remove(bird)

for bird in greg_birds:
    if bird in duplicates:
        greg_birds.remove(bird)

print(f'Ben saw {len(ben_birds)} Birds that no one else saw')
print(f'Steve saw {len(steve_birds)} Birds that no one else saw')
print(f'Greg saw {len(greg_birds)} Birds that no one else saw')
```